# Split Table column in Dynamic data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic-data

I am using an integer field in the DB to represent collection of booleans in order to save some space. the integer is used in my Business logic and transformed into collection Boolean attributes.
i'v now decided to add "Admin" section to the site using Dynamic data feature, and i am wondering whether there is an option to show the Booleans that represent that integer.
i know how to Hide a certain column (avoid scaffold) but i don't know how to add "virtual" column to the Dynamic control.

Maybe Sql View is the answer here? is there an easy way to bind the dynamic data into SQL view instead of the real table?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a custom field template that would handle the logic of splitting/"joining" the boolean values into an integer?

MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488523.aspx

Video:
http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/video-291.aspx